# How Do You String Manipulate Return Results from Timestream?

Tags: amazon-timestream

For a simple query such as:

`SELECT measure_value::varchar FROM "mydb"."mytable" LIMIT 5`

which produces:

| measure_value::varchar |
| --- |
| Travis |
| Paul |
| Jon |

How can you modify the query to show:

| measure_value::varchar |
| --- |
| Hello Travis |
| Hello Paul |
| Hello Jon |

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with string functions:

```
SELECT concat('Hello ', measure_value::varchar) FROM "mydb"."mytable" LIMIT 5
```

Care must be be taken with quotes as string literals should be single quotes. To utilize a single quote within the string, escape it with another single quote (eg. `'One ''s''.'` to make `One 's'`).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/string-functions.html